# how to make multiple object run animation at the same time in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3 object from the same prefab. I run animation of these object by call SetTrigger .
But the animation is not occured in the same time.

I want to animate object to dissapear in the same time.

```
private void Destoy(List<Item> dupList)
{
    foreach (Item dup in dupList)
    {
        dup.color.anim.SetTrigger("Destroy");
        Destroy(dup.color, 1);
    }
    color.anim.SetTrigger("Destroy");
    Destroy(color,1);
}
```

When SetTrigger call , animation was not run at the same time.
Remark : this Destroy function is called from coroutine.

[see in motion picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BbBe.gif)

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: first share your tried code and follow up error message if you have one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To start a coroutine you need to create an "IEnumerator" method, in your case it should be "IEnumerator Destroy(List<Item> dupList)", otherwise it will not work as a coroutine and by using coroutines you can use the "yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f)" to wait 1 second and then call Destroy(dup.color).

Comment: Also you can use "Animation Events" to call a function through the animation. For example you can set an animation event at the end of the animation clip to "Destroy(dup.color)" instead of having a delay call.